# AngularJS Alert service: fading out ng-repeat item

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

In AngularJS I have created a service:

```
services.service('Alerts', function($rootScope, $timeout) {
    this.add = function(content) {
        $rootScope.alerts.push({
            content: content
        });

        $timeout(function () {
            $rootScope.alerts.pop();
            console.log($rootScope.alerts[0]);
        }, 1000);
    }
}).run(function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.alerts = [];
});
```

and implemented my HTML code:

```
<div class="alerts">
    <div class="alert fade" ng-repeat="alert in alerts" bs-alert="alert"></div>
</div>
```

It fades in perfectly fine, but instead of simply "popping" it out of the table after a second I'd like to obtain the element and then use element.fadeOut() (jquery)

I can't obtain the actual alert element.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do something very similar and here's what I came up with using the $timeout service, although I didn't use jQuery at all.
http://plnkr.co/edit/Mi0xaPJa6pLWkBq60Ohn?p=preview

Obviously the animation css needs a little work, but I mostly copied it from the angular [ng-repeat docs](http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.8/docs/api/ng.directive%3angRepeat).